# Convert Linq Query Expression to Method Syntax equivalent

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I use LINQ, C#, EF4.

I have this query expression in Linq. I need to convert in a equivalent in Method Syntax but I have some doubt on the struction. Could you provide me a good example. Thanks for your help.

```
var myContentsForAuthor = from c in context.CmsContents
                          join a in context.CmsAuthors on c.AuthorId equals a.AuthorId
                          join u in context.aspnet_Users on a.UserId equals u.UserId
                          orderby c.Title ascending 
                          where u.UserId == myUserGuid && c.IsDeleted == false && c.Title.Contains(nameSearchString)
                          select c;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this gets complicated because of the transparent identifiers, but something like:

```
var myContentsForAuthor = context.CmsContents
                                 .Join(context.CmsAuthors,
                                       c => c.AuthorId
                                       a => a.AuthorId,
                                       (c, a) => new { c, a })
                                 .Join(context.aspnet_Users,
                                       z => z.a.UserId,
                                       u => u.UserId,
                                       (z, u) => new { z, u })
                                 .OrderBy(zz => zz.z.c.Title)
                                 .Where(zz => zz.u.UserId == myUserGuid &&
                                              zz.z.c.IsDeleted == false &&
                                              zz.z.c.Title.Contains(nameSearch))
                                 .Select(zz => zz.z.c);
```

Comment: Thanks John for your reply, what do you mean by transparent identifiers?

Comment: @GibboK: It's tricky to explain in comments - read my blog post about query translations: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jon once again for your time

Comment: Jon sorry I have another dobt, if I want update the .OrderBy(zz => zz.z.c.Title) instead c.Description or another field dynamically using a string variable like "sortExpression" would work?? I replace wit this code .OrderBy(zz => "zz.z.c." + sortExpression) but does not work. Could you please help me on this I would really appreciate it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @GibboK: That's a really different question. It sounds like you're after Dynamic Linq: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx